# Dificuldade em atualizar dados com angular e php

Tags: php, angularjs, pdo

Boa tarde

Estou tentando atualizar dados no banco e não consigo.
Se eu uso mysqli, aparece o seguinte aviso no console:
"http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/VigilantesComunitarios/admin/php/atualizarUsuario.php 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Se eu uso conexão com mysql e PDO, nada acontece, nem aviso no console aparece.

Meu arquivo js:

```
app.controller("AtualizarUsuarioController", function ($scope, $window, $http, $location) {

$scope.usuario = {
    'id': $window.localStorage.getItem('idUsuarios'),
    'nome': $window.localStorage.getItem('nome'),
    'email': $window.localStorage.getItem('email')
}

//$location.path('/atualizarUsuario' + $scope.usuario.id);
$scope.atualizarUsuario = function (usuario) {
    $http.post("admin/php/atualizarUsuario.php", usuario).then(function (data){
        $location.path("#/usuarios");
    });
};
});
```

php:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

include_once ("conPDO.php");
$pdo = conectar();

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($postdata);
$id = $data->id;
$nome = $data->nome;
$email = $data->email;
$senha = $data->senha;

$senha = sha1($senha);

$usuarioAtual=$pdo->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET nome=:nome, email=:email, senha=:senha WHERE id=:id");
$usuarioAtual->bindValue(":nome", $nome);
$usuarioAtual->bindValue(":email", $email);
$usuarioAtual->bindValue(":senha", $senha);
$usuarioAtual->bindValue(":id", $id);
$usuarioAtual->execute();
```

E minha estrutura de pastas.
[image: Pastas]

Retorno do console após print_r e console.log
[image: Dados no console]

Comment: Já verificou se a URL da APi está correta, não conheço php mas eu colocaria um print no método que faz update pra ver se ele ta sendo chamado

Comment: Sim, a url está correta.
Uso o postman, aplicativo do chrome, para verificar isso e passar dados.

Comment: Poderia postar o código do dos arquivos "con.php" e "conPDO.php"?

Comment: @GustavoSevero internal error significa que houve uma falha no servidor. Vá até a aba Networks do navegador e verifique o arquivo atualizarUsuario.php que vai ter a response do servidor contendo o erro. Se não tiver, verifique os logs do servidor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu problema pode estar no método utilizado no `$http`, no seu caso você está usando `PUT`. No passado tive problemas ao usar ele também pois existem configurações e (alguns casos) limitações de servidor que impedem que o `PUT` seja chamado.

Use `POST`, fora algumas particularidades - que não vão implicar no seu caso- você não vai ter problema e pode ser que resolva.

```
$http.post([url], [data], [config]);
```

Obs.: Não utilize print screen do seu código, utilize o código mesmo.

---

#### Editado:

Outro ponto importante seria de utilizar `print_r` (no php) e `console.log` (no Angular) para depurar melhor o que está acontecendo e onde está o problema.

```
//No AngularJs
$scope.atualizarUsuario = function (usuario) {
    $http.post("admin/php/atualizarUsuario.php", usuario).then(function (data){
        console.log(data); //'data' pois é o valor definido dentro do `function` do `then`
        $location.path("#/usuarios");
    });
};

//E no PHP
$usuarioAtual->execute();
print_r($usuarioAtual);
```

Deste modo você tem uma visão melhor do que está acontecendo.

Comment: Fiz alterações Celso.
Mudei de put pra post, tb... Mas mesmo assim, nada, não está atualizando

Comment: de um `print_r($usuarioAtual)` e um `console.log(data)` dentro do .then do $http para ver o que o php retorna. Tente sempre buscar os logs. Não vai aparecer nenhum erro pois você não está pedindo para exibir nada, nem no php nem no angular.

Comment: O print_r($dados) coloco no final do meu código php?

Comment: Pode ser sim, e você pode utilizar outros 'prints', como por exemplo do $postdata para confirmar que os dados estão realmente chegando.

Comment: Existe alguma variável indefinida, na linha 14 do seu arquivo. Busque por ela e veja se realmente foi definida.

Comment: Desculpe, mas como assim? Está tudo certo. Estava dando erro pq eu tinha colocado $print_r, depois corrigi pra print_r

Comment: Celso, coloquei, aqui no post, um print do retorno no console.

Comment: Ok, a data está chegando corretamente, mas qual o retorno do `$usuarioAtual`, ou seja, do processo de atualizar os dados no banco?

Comment: Está dando fatalError... E até já vi onde é.

Comment: Agora corrigi e funcionou Celso.
Eu estava colocando o id errado no SQL.
Valeu por me dar essa dica do print_r, pois não sabia que ver isso usando:

"$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($postdata);"

E tb não sabia que poderia usar no final do código, tb, para ver o que aparecia.
Usando PDO, fica mais complicado debugar SQL, não é?

Comment: Sim, fica, mas sempre uso esse mesmo processo de dar um print_r no .php e console.log no .js, assim consigo sempre depurar o que está acontecendo. Muitas vezes são erros bobos que a gente não percebe. Mas bom que ajudou! =D